# Setting label with ng-options and 'as' ('track by' alternative)

Tags: angularjs

I need all of my drop down menu options to have a label that matches their displayed value. Currently the code I use to create the options is `ng-options="country.Code as country.Country for country in countries"`. I know the preferred way to do this is with `track by`, but since I already use `as`, my code breaks when I do so. How can I work around this?

Comment: What's `track as`? Don't you mean track by?

Comment: I do, my apologies

Comment: So what error are you getting?

Comment: My select displays only empty options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `track by` in [NgOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) when using `as` but it's important to set the complete country object *(not country.Code)* to the NgModel or else the track by statement will fail.

Try it like this

```
ng-options="country as country.Country for country in countries track by country.Code"
```